# Trouble accessing information from a dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary

I am merging lists together to create dictionaries. I am having trouble though calling the keys after creating the dictionary.

```
import xlrd

from xlrd import open_workbook
book = open_workbook('inputme.xlsx')
sheet0 = book.sheet_by_index(0)


sociallab= sheet0.row(0)
socialrank= sheet0.row(1)
OCDlab= sheet0.row(2)
OCDrank= sheet0.row(3)
BDDlab=sheet0.row(4)
BDDrank= sheet0.row(5)
EDlab= sheet0.row(4)
EDrank= sheet0.row(5)

social = dict(zip(socialrank,sociallab))
OCD = dict(zip(OCDrank, OCDlab))
BDD = dict(zip(BDDrank, BDDlab))
ED = dict(zip(EDrank, EDlab))

print(ED.keys())
ed1 = ED["number:1.0"]
print(ed1)
```

When I run this I get:

```
dict_keys([number:3.0, number:4.0, number:8.0, number:7.0, number:5.0, number:1.0, number:2.0, number:6.0])
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Lee\Dropbox\Python\ME.py", line 28, in <module>
    ed1 = ED["number:1.0"]
KeyError: 'number:1.0'
```

I must be doing something wrong with understanding how to read the keylist, but am unable to figure out what I am doing wrong. I'm new to this so it might be very basic but I can't find anything in documentation that clarifies.

Any advice?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the representation hints (because there aren't any quotation marks around the values), the keys aren't actually strings.

```
dict_keys([number:3.0, number:4.0, number:8.0, number:7.0, number:5.0, number:1.0, number:2.0, number:6.0])
```

If you `print(list(map(type, ED)))` you'll probably see a lot of `<class 'xlrd.sheet.Cell'>` references.  You might be able to use `.row_values()` instead.  Compare (using some data I have at hand):

```
>>> print(sheet0.row(6)[:4])
[text:u'     Specialists', empty:'', number:585.0, number:123.0]
>>> print(list(map(type, sheet0.row(6)[:4])))
[<class 'xlrd.sheet.Cell'>, <class 'xlrd.sheet.Cell'>, <class 'xlrd.sheet.Cell'>, <class 'xlrd.sheet.Cell'>]
>>> print(sheet0.row_values(6)[:4])
[u'     Specialists', '', 585.0, 123.0]
>>> print(list(map(type, sheet0.row_values(6)[:4])))
[<type 'unicode'>, <type 'str'>, <type 'float'>, <type 'float'>]
```

Comment: Thanks! row_values fixed it